# SQL - How to fill NULL values with NOT NULL value of previous matched record with LEFT Join

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose I have a 3 Tables

TABLE1

```
ID   PERSON
1    ABC
3    DEF
5    GHI
7    JKL
```

TABLE2

```
ID   SPORT
1    CRICKET
2    RUNNING
3    TENNIS
1    HOCKEY
3    FOOTBALL
```

TABLE3

```
SPORT      PLAYER
CRICKET    SACHIN
RUNNING    USAIN
TENNIS     NULL
HOCKEY     NULL
FOOTBALL   MESSI
```

WHEN I USE THIS QUERY

```
SELECT A.PERSON, B.SPORT, C.PLAYER
FROM TABLE1 A LEFT JOIN TABLE2 B ON A.ID = B.ID
     LEFT JOIN TABLE3 C ON B.SPORT = C.SPORT
```

This giving me result -

```
PERSON     SPORT      PLAYER
ABC        CRICKET    SACHIN
ABC        HOCKEY     NULL
DEF        TENNIS     NULL
GHI        NULL       NULL
JKL        NULL       NULL
DEF        FOOTBALL   MESSI
```

I want NULL value in PLAYER column to be populate with previous PLAYER value for same person.
I want query result as below

```
PERSON     SPORT      PLAYER
ABC        CRICKET    SACHIN
ABC        HOCKEY     SACHIN
DEF        FOOTBALL   MESSI
DEF        TENNIS     MESSI
GHI        NULL       NULL
JKL        NULL       NULL
```

Is any way to achieve this. Please help

Comment: _Previous_ - according to what?

Comment: @jarlh Please see the last query result, I have mentioned person ABC that have SACHIN & NULL value associated with it, so I want both ABC Person should return SACHIN instead of SACHIN & NULL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Previous" has no meaning in SQL queries unless there is a column specifying the ordering.  With such a column, you can do:

```
SELECT A.PERSON, B.SPORT,
       COALESCE(LAG(C.PLAYER IGNORE NULLS) OVER (PARTITION BY A.PERSON ORDER BY <ordering col>) as Player
FROM TABLE1 A LEFT JOIN 
     TABLE2 B
     ON A.ID = B.ID LEFT JOIN
     TABLE3 C
     ON B.SPORT = C.SPORT
```

If you just want `NULL` values to be filled in with *any* non-`NULL` value, use `MAX()`:

```
SELECT A.PERSON, B.SPORT,
       COALESCE(MAX(C.PLAYER IGNORE NULLS) OVER (PARTITION BY A.PERSON) as Player
FROM TABLE1 A LEFT JOIN 
     TABLE2 B
     ON A.ID = B.ID LEFT JOIN
     TABLE3 C
     ON B.SPORT = C.SPORT
```